# Roof gable transition

Tags: roofing, flashing

The house I currently stay in has sunlight shining through from below at this point. I would like to know the flashing detail that a professional roofer might employ.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of this hole from the interior?

Comment: a picture from the inside would look like an L of light on the side and under the facia board as it plunges through the singles